# How to center image in a pecentage div

Tags: html, center

I have 3 divs in a row (floated) with a width of 33.333333333333%

In this div I have a img and I want to center it.

I can do this closley by using margin: 0 40%; but if I have bigger or smaller screen its not centered.

```
Code bellow
```

[JSfiddle link][1]  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/3gGDZ/

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` to your images than use `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `margin: 0 40%;`

**Example:**

```
.button1 img,
.button2 img,
.button3 img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8A8bn/

Comment: Can you provide us a JsFiddle, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Add display: block; on your images, than the margin: 0 auto will work.